# Flex Profiler - Alternative?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, profiling

### Question

Is there an alternative (free) tool for profiling flex applications that will show things like memory use, function calls, execution times, object allocations, etc?

### Background

Flex has a built-in profiler but it requires a Premium license.  At work, we currently have standard licenses.  We will upgrade to premium but that process will take months.  This week, there is an immediate need to improve performance and eliminate bottlenecks and memory issues.

We've done as much as we can "by hand," refactoring code to use weak references, instantiate fewer objects, remove nested containers and a handful of other tweaks.  Things are still a bit slow so we are at the point where we REALLY need a profiler.

### Summary

After a lot of Googling, all results point to the built-in flex profiler.  Surely, there is an open source or free alternative that we can download, immediately.  Even a profiler that was originally intended for Flash (instead of flex) would probably do the trick.  Any recommendations are appreciated!

Comment: For the record, the built in profiler IS in fact a SFW file loaded before the actual app.

Comment: Thanks. I clarified my question because what I meant by "a SWF profiler would do" was that a tool developed for "Flash profiling" would likely work just as well for "Flex profiling," since Flex compiles down to a SWF file. I did not mean to imply that I was seeking a profiler that "IS a SWF file."  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out this page : http://jpauclair.net/flashpreloadprofiler/

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising.  I see the page also references MonsterDebugger.  I vaguely remember trying to use that before.  I'll look into that too since it can work in conjunction with the tool in your link.

Comment: Monster Debugger is a nice tool but you can't really profile functions with it. You do get, however, memory consumption and visual debugging in real time. It's really easy to set up but I got some bugs with it (like app hanging). Use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the open source [SWFWire Debugger](http://www.swfwire.com/debugger).  You should be able to get some useful info with the memory graph, object graph, and method timing features.

*Disclaimer: This is my own project*

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe Scout](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/) just came out recently that has more information. I have yet to find an article that describes how to use it with Flex but it should give you more data to measure.